# Can not use instance method implementation inside another definition

Tags: haskell, fold

Hello i do not understand why i do have the following problem :
I am trying to define `taxes` definition for `Company` using `taxes` implementation  from `Employee`.I do not understand why i face the following errors:

```
data Employee=Employee{
        age::Int,
        name::String,
        job::Job,
        wage::Double
    }
data Job= Worker | Manager |Unemployed deriving(Eq,Ord,Show)

data Company=Company{
    compName::String,
    year::Int,
    employees::[Employee]
}

class Charges a where 
     taxes::a->Double
instance Charges Employee where 
    taxes Employee{age=a,wage=w}=fromIntegral a * w
```

**Implementation 1:**

```
instance Charges Company where 
    taxes comp=foldl ((+).taxes) 0 employees
```

Error:

```
Couldn't match type `[Employee]' with `Double'
  Expected type: Company -> Double
    Actual type: Company -> [Employee]
```

Why is it a problem since i take an `Employee` one by one i apply `taxes` which is already implemented for `Employee` and i add it to the counter??

**Implementation2** - using foldr

```
 instance Charges Company where 
        taxes comp =foldl ((+).taxes) 0 (employees comp)
```

Error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Company -> Double'
                  with actual type `Double'
    * Possible cause: `foldr' is applied to too many arguments
```

I see no more then 3 arguments what is the problem?

Comment: What about `taxes = foldl ((+).taxes) 0 . employees`?

Comment: A simpler approach is however `taxes = sum . map taxes . employees`.

Comment: Have you tried `foldr`?. I haven't ckeck it but I think the type of `(+) . taxes` is `Company -> Double -> Double` so in this case `foldl` takes an input function of type `Double -> Company -> Double`. wrong types

Comment: Please paste code you're actually using, preferably with the *full* error message, not just a snippet. Your supposed foldr code uses foldl but the error message says you are using foldr.

Comment: I do not understand.If i use :  `taxes=foldl ((+).taxes) .employees ` this means that 
i  am trying to compose a partially applied function which is `fodl` in our case,since the source parameter is not provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is already a function in the Prelude that is excellent for summing lists of numbers. Why are we reinventing summation with a fold? Break the problem down into a few parts:

- Find the company's employees
- Compute taxes for each
- Sum the results

Thus:

```
instance Charges Company where 
    taxes = sum . map taxes . employees
```